# Configure WCF Client to Use Web Services Security Kerberos Token Profile 1.1

Tags: wcf, security, client, kerberos

Morning,

Does anyone know how to configure WCF (any binding type, we are currently using WSHttpBinding but am happy to move to a CustomBinding or alternative if necessary) to use

Web Services Security Kerberos Token Profile 1.1

the details of which can be found here:

http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/16788/wss-v1.1-spec-os-KerberosTokenProfile.pdf

In particular I would like to know how to include the Security BinarySecurityToken and the SecurityTokenReference sections in the SOAP header. Example (taken from the above document)below:

```
<S11:Envelope xmlns:S11="..." xmlns:wsse="..." xmlns:wsu="...">
  <S11:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss225 kerberos-token-profile-1.1#Kerberosv5_AP_REQ" wsu:Id="MyToken">
        boIBxDCCAcCgAwIBBaEDAgEOogcD...
      </wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      ...
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        <wsse:Reference URI="#MyToken" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-kerberos-token232 profile-1.1#Kerberosv5_AP_REQ" >
        </wsse:Reference>
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
      ...
    </wsse:Security>
  </S11:Header>
  <S11:Body>
  ...
  </S11:Body>
</S11:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance, Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730294.aspx):

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="MyBinding">
        <security mode="Message>
            <message   
                clientCredentialType="Windows"
                negotiateServiceCredential="false"
                establishSecurityContext="false"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work. We end up with a RequestSecurityToken in the SOAP body. Its structure doesnt look like the specification.

Comment: And you're using that binding configuration verbatim and nothing else?

Comment: No. We are using https, so the mode we have set to TransportWithMessageCredential. We have some timeouts set and some readerQuotas but nothing that I would expect would interfere with the inclusion of the Kerberos token.

Comment: In all honesty I've never used kerberos tokens, only SAML tokens. Check out this MSDN documentation on how negotiateServiceCredential impacts the use of the Kerberos token profile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.messagesecurityoverhttp.negotiateservicecredential.aspx